# Check between a tag for empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want check between a tag if empty was between it append a text, How is it?

Example: if empty was between tag `<span></span>` append phrase `There is not` between `.exist`.

Comment: Is that a complicated way to say: "I want to check if an element has no content"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will put the text in the span element.

```
 $("span:empty").text("There is not!")
```

To check if empty and put the text in different element use:

```
if ($("span:empty").length != 0) {
    $('.empty').text("There is not!")
}
```

[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/wzqQj/1/)

```
if ($('span:empty').length != 0) {
    $('.exist').show().html($('<b/>').text('There is not').wrap($('<p/>')));
}
```

[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/h39S3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one span tag

```
if ($("span").html() == ""){
    $(".exist").append('There is not');
}
```